# is there a way to choose all fields when creating a view?

Tags: 2003

Im creating a view and need to chose all 600 fields to appear in that view, how would I check all of the checkboxes instead of one by one? SharePoint 2003

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no native "select all". But you can use jQuery to check them all for you (using the console in IE Dev Tools)

```
$('#tbodyViewColumns').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

This is an example for SP 2013, where `tbodyViewColumns` is the section with the columns selection.

Comment: Wow! SharePoint 2003, that brings back memories.
I really hated that ViewEdit interface and wrote 
[a BookMarklet to make it do Drag/Drop](http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Drag_Drop_Columns_in_the_EditView_Page)